# An icon that represents "End Game" in iPhone app

Tags: icons, iphone, toolbar

I'm stumped. I would like to have an icon in the toolbar that represents "End Game". My app is a scorekeeping app, and when the user wants to end the game and start with a fresh scoreboard, they would click this icon. I've thought about something as simple as an "X", but I'm not satisfied with this idea.

EDIT

I'd prefer an icon with no text. It suits my app better and generally is better for icons in the iphone toolbar.

Also, sometimes the user merely wants to end the game (and the fact that this will reset the scores to 0 is irrelevant). I think I overemphasized the 'refreshing' part in my original question.

Comment: Seems like a little stop sign would suffice. Not quite "end game" but you're just "stopping" the game, right?

Comment: That doesn't sound like "end", it sounds like "refresh" or "restart". I would think something like the refresh glyph from a browser would work. Or, if your Start button is still visible, either adding a "Reset" button or changing its caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with overslacked, it also sounds like a "refresh" to me. Use a refresh glyph:
[image]

Comment: This is my favorite icon so far.

Comment: This is my favorite icon so far.

I only have one reservation about this. Sometimes the user will think to themselves, "Game over, I want to start a new game." In that case, this icon is perfect. In other cases they will think "Game over". In which case, this icon is not intuitive.

I realize now I should have worded my original question better.

Answer (score 3):

I've used 'Exit' in a mini game, and placed it on a door which fit the scenario as the game space used a room metaphor. This seemed to work for people though it took them a moment to understand it as the game's exit and not a game feature. No mis-taps though.

[image: Exit Door]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [image]

Comment: Please expand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would try one of these:

END

[image]

NEXT TURN, PASS - used in lot of turn based games (Heroes series for example)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking a new doc type icon. ie. a rectangle with an asterisk on the top right hand corner.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach this differently. I would have a "New Game" button or icon instead. Ultimately you'd want your users to understand that a new game will start when leaving the current one.

After clicking the button you might prompt/remind the user the the current game will end and if it is ok to continue.

Comment: I like where you're going with this. Unfortunately, the most intuitive "new game" icons may be confusing in this app. A "+" could be interpreted as "Add Player" or "Add to Score" as opposed to "Start New Game". I will think on this some more.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the game's icon to symbolize the game and a white-washed or wire-frame version of the same icon to symbolize a new (blank) game.

If you add an asterisk on the top right corner of the white-washed/wire-frame icon, as @Mica stated, this will be even clearer.